# Webpack hot module replacement lists updated React components in console but does not update them

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

After changing some text in my About component and saving the file, I can see the following logs in my console:

```
client.js?6a8d:123 [HMR] bundle rebuilding
client.js?6a8d:126 [HMR] bundle rebuilt in 3786ms
process-update.js:27 [HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
bootstrap 5e8b103…:45 XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:3001/dist/5e8b1032c40f91ebd6ce.hot-update.json".hotDownloadManifest @ bootstrap 5e8b103…:45hotCheck @ bootstrap 5e8b103…:264check @ process-update.js:64module.exports @ process-update.js:28processMessage @ client.js?6a8d:139handleMessage @ client.js?6a8d:65
index.js:81 [React Transform HMR] Patching Marketing
process-update.js:100 [HMR] Updated modules:
process-update.js:102 [HMR]  - ./src/containers/Marketing/About.js
process-update.js:102 [HMR]  - ./src/containers/Marketing/index.js
process-update.js:107 [HMR] App is up to date.
```

However, the DOM is not updated and the only way to get the updated text is to do a full browser refresh.

Any ideas on how to solve this? I am fairly sure this was setup correctly in the past and I'm not sure what I did which made it stop working. I can only recall adding code splitting in a few places recently but the about component is part of the main build.

Here's the content of `...-hot-update.json`:

```
{"h":"c6abfe651b7516cb5169","c":[0]}
```

`...-hot-update.js` appears to contain the code of the modified component.

Here's my development webpack config:

```js
require('babel-polyfill')

// Webpack config for development
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var assetsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../static/dist')
var host = (process.env.HOST || 'localhost')
var port = (+process.env.PORT + 1) || 3001

// const { CommonsChunkPlugin } = webpack.optimize

// https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/webpack-isomorphic-tools
var WebpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin = require('webpack-isomorphic-tools/plugin')
var webpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin = new WebpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin(require('./webpack-isomorphic-tools'))

var babelrc = fs.readFileSync('./.babelrc')
var babelrcObject = {}

try {
  babelrcObject = JSON.parse(babelrc)
} catch (err) {
  console.error('==>     ERROR: Error parsing your .babelrc.')
  console.error(err)
}


var babelrcObjectDevelopment = babelrcObject.env && babelrcObject.env.development || {}

// merge global and dev-only plugins
var combinedPlugins = babelrcObject.plugins || []
combinedPlugins = combinedPlugins.concat(babelrcObjectDevelopment.plugins)

var babelLoaderQuery = Object.assign({}, babelrcObjectDevelopment, babelrcObject, {plugins: combinedPlugins})
delete babelLoaderQuery.env

// Since we use .babelrc for client and server, and we don't want HMR enabled on the server, we have to add
// the babel plugin react-transform-hmr manually here.

// make sure react-transform is enabled
babelLoaderQuery.plugins = babelLoaderQuery.plugins || []
var reactTransform = null
for (var i = 0; i < babelLoaderQuery.plugins.length; ++i) {
  var plugin = babelLoaderQuery.plugins[i]
  if (Array.isArray(plugin) && plugin[0] === 'react-transform') {
    reactTransform = plugin
  }
}

if (!reactTransform) {
  reactTransform = ['react-transform', {transforms: []}]
  babelLoaderQuery.plugins.push(reactTransform)
}

if (!reactTransform[1] || !reactTransform[1].transforms) {
  reactTransform[1] = Object.assign({}, reactTransform[1], {transforms: []})
}

// make sure react-transform-hmr is enabled
reactTransform[1].transforms.push({
  transform: 'react-transform-hmr',
  imports: ['react'],
  locals: ['module']
})

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '..'),
  entry: {
    'main': [
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=http://' + host + ':' + port + '/__webpack_hmr',
      'bootstrap-sass!./src/styles/theme/bootstrap.config.js',
      // 'font-awesome-webpack!./src/styles/theme/font-awesome.config.js',
      './src/client.js',
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: assetsPath,
    filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js',
    publicPath: 'http://' + host + ':' + port + '/dist/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['babel?' + JSON.stringify(babelLoaderQuery)]},
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
      { test: /\.less$/, loader: 'style!css?modules&importLoaders=2&sourceMap&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:5]!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 version!less?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap' },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'style!css?sourceMap&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:5]!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 version!sass?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap'
      },
      { test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file" },
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" },
      { test: webpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin.regular_expression('images'), loader: 'url-loader?limit=10240' }
    ]
  },
  progress: true,
  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: [
      'src',
      'node_modules'
    ],
    extensions: ['', '.json', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  plugins: [
    // hot reload
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/webpack-stats\.json$/),
    // TODO: where should I put this in array?
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'common' }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __CLIENT__: true,
      __SERVER__: false,
      __DEVELOPMENT__: true,
      __DEVTOOLS__: true,  // <-------- DISABLE redux-devtools HERE
      'process.env.API_URL': JSON.stringify(process.env.API_URL),
      'process.env.PUBLIC_URL': JSON.stringify(process.env.PUBLIC_URL),
      'process.env.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY': JSON.stringify(process.env.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY),
      'process.env.INTERCOM_APP_ID': JSON.stringify(process.env.INTERCOM_APP_ID),
      'process.env.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_CODE': JSON.stringify(process.env.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_CODE),
      'process.env.FEATURE_MONITORING': JSON.stringify(process.env.FEATURE_MONITORING),
    }),
    webpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin.development()
  ],
}
```

**UPDATE:** I just noticed that HMR is working properly for some components (my header and footer for example) but not for others (content of About page). Can't figure out yet what it is that makes some components fail to update.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same fail type: everything "looks" like it hot reloads (correct files showing up in console, compile succeeding), but the DOM simply wasn't updating. Full refresh required to update.

Fix for me was: **Do not mix Stateless and 'normal' React Components in a single file**.

Multiple components *styles* in a single file failed with HMR.

In short, keep Stateless components:

```
export default const MyCom = () => <div></div>
```

Separate (files) from class based components:

```
export default class NextCom extends React.Component {
  render () { return <div></div> }
}
```

Putting those two examples into a single file produced the HMR-working-but-failing-to-update-DOM issue you seem to be having too.